# Visual interface for TemperatureControl trait, google device actions

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-smart-home

I have a water heater whose temperature I have to control and view from my Google Home App. The TempratureControl trait in google device actions enables the utilization of google assistant voice interface for the following things :

- Setting temperature
- Asking current temperature
- Setting temperature range that the device is capable of reaching

(The problem is TempControl trait has no ui as compared to TempSetting trait but TempSetting is for thermostats)

Can anyone suggest, how to get a visual interface on Google Home App to accomplish above mentioned things.

URL for TempeartureControl trait.
https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/temperaturecontrol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may not be a visual UI for every trait right now.

Comment: Do you have a timeline for when the ui will be available ?

Comment: No I don't. You can send feedback in the app for features you want to see.